$\{A_n\}$ is Kuratowski convergent provided whenever hAni hits a basic open set V frequently, then $\{A_n\}$hits V eventually.
we define Kuratowski convergence like this:
Let $ A_1, A_2, A_3,...$ be a sequence of closed sets in a metric space (X,d).
Define the upper and lower closed limits $LsA_n$ and $LiA_n$ of the sequence as
follows:
$LsA_n$ = {x ∈ X : each ball with center x hits $A_n$ frequently};
$LiA_n$ = {x ∈ X : each ball with center x hits $A_n$ eventually}.
Clearly, $LiA_n \subset LsA_n$ and it is easy to show that both the upper and
lower closed limits are closed subsets of X (though possibly empty).
When the reverse inclusion also holds, we get $LiA_n = LsA_n$ and in this case $A_n$ is declared Kuratowski convergent to their common value.
Now I have tp prove that:
$\{A_n\}$ is Kuratowski convergent provided whenever hAni hits a basic open set V frequently, then $\{A_n\}$hits V eventually.
I tried to prove that like this:
let $x\in LsA_n$ we have to prove that $x\in LiA_n$
let $\epsilon > 0$
then B(x,$\epsilon$) hits $A_n$ frequently.
since B(x,$\epsilon$) is an open set then we can write B(x,$\epsilon$)=$\bigcup_{i\in\Delta^*} V_i $
(when $ \Delta^* \subset \Delta $ and $\{ V_i \}$ is a base for X )
then $A_n \cap \bigcup_{i\in\Delta^*} V_i \neq \emptyset$ frequently
then $\bigcup_{i\in\Delta^*} ( A_n \cap V_i ) \neq \emptyset$ frequently
first I thought there exists $ i\in\Delta^* $
such that $ A_n \cap V_i \neq \emptyset $ frequently
but now I can see that is not true.bacause  maybe $\Delta^*$  is infinite.
So I don't know how I can prove that. Any help?
